# Pandas: how to select columns to be displayed in groupby results?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 10 columns from which I want to list some columns of rows where `ROUGE_L` is maximum grouped by `Model`, I tried:

```
sdf = df.groupby(['Model','Checkpoint'])['ROUGE_L'].max()
```

It prints:

```
Model  Checkpoint    ROUGE_L
4      1005100       0.204
       1010200       0.202
       1015300       0.205
       1020400       0.203
       1025500       0.204
                     ...  
16000  1030600       0.396
       1035700       0.396
       1040800       0.408
```

But I look for this:

```
Model  Checkpoint    ROUGE_L
4      1005300       0.205
16000  1040800       0.408
```

I didn't find a statement that does above in similar questions.

Comment: Could you please do explain logic of how to get the element from `ROUGE_L` column? Sorry but samples are not clear at the moment.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the max value of `ROUGE_L`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more precision about your original dataframe but the code below should work:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby("Model")["ROUGE_L"].idxmax()]
   Model  Checkpoint  ROUGE_L
2      4     1015300    0.205
7  16000     1040800    0.408
```

To select columns, append `[["Model", "Checkpoint", "ROUGE_L"]]` at the previous instruction:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby("Model")["ROUGE_L"].idxmax()][["Model", "Checkpoint", "ROUGE_L"]]
   Model  Checkpoint  ROUGE_L
2      4     1015300    0.205
7  16000     1040800    0.408
```

Comment: please, read my update.... where `Checkpoint` is selected in your command? please note the columns could be more than these 3

Comment: I select rows meet the condition "ROUGE_L is maximum grouped by Model".

Comment: Good, but I don't want to show other columns, just these three in each rows. I thought it must be a basic commend, couldn't know that's so complicated!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Don't forget we don't know your original dataframe... We tried to guess and help you.

Comment: now I explicitly said the columns are more than these 3, however, without that also one shouldn't suppose columns are these 3.... That's strange! I thought it must be the basic use of data frames, its like `select x,y, max(z) from Table grouped by x` while the columns could be more...

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but I thought it had to be simpler and shorter command, anyways, thanks...

Comment: Suggested article that could help you: [Translating SQL to pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/translating-sql-to-pandas-8f4ae0268899)

Answer (score 0):

If we are looking for Checkpoint by max ROUGE_L for each Model group, then:

```
df.set_index('ROUGE_L').sort_index().reset_index().groupby(['Model'], as_index=False).last()
```

**Output**

```
   Model    Checkpoint  ROUGE_L
2   4       1015300     0.205
7   16000   1040800     0.408
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple max values in the same group and you want to retrieve all, you can use

```py
mask = df.groupby('Model')['ROUGE_L'].apply(lambda group: group == group.max())
df_ = df[mask]
```

```
print(df_)

   Model  Checkpoint  ROUGE_L
2      4     1015300    0.205
5      4     1025500    0.205
8  16000     1040800    0.408
```

Comment: It had to be more simpler than that, also please note the colunms are more than these....